# Using a second foreach loop in WooCommerce attributes list values as single <li> elements

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

**I am trying to get product attributes(only selected ones) to show as a list like in the first picture below:**

[image: screenshot of how the list should look]

**Unfortunately my list looks like this at the moment:** 
*(How can i divide the values with another foreach statement?)*

[image]

**Furthermore my code/shortcode shows all product attributes found and would want to use something like: [product_attributes:sizes|color|print] to select only the attributes i want to show.**

```
add_filter( 'wplister_process_template_html', 'my_wplister_template_filter_product_attributes_list', 10, 3 );
function my_wplister_template_filter_product_attributes_list( $html, $item, $images ) {

    $post_id    = $item['parent_id'] ? $item['parent_id'] : $item['post_id'];
    $attributes = ProductWrapper::getAttributes( $post_id );

    $attributes_list = '';
    foreach ($attributes as $name => $value) {
        $value           = '<li>' . str_replace( '|', ', ', $value ) . '</li>';
        $attributes_list .= '<div>';
        $attributes_list .= '<p>' . $name . ': <p>';
        $attributes_list .= '<ul class="variation">' . $value . '</ul>';
        $attributes_list .= '</ul>';
        $attributes_list .= '</div>';   
    }

    $html = str_replace( '[[product_attributes_list]]', $attributes_list, $html );
    return $html;
}
```

How to use a second foreach loop in list values as single `<li>` elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really test it. I have make some changes in your code to make a second foreach loop.

Try this:

```
add_filter( 'wplister_process_template_html', 'my_wplister_template_filter_product_attributes_list', 10, 3 );
function my_wplister_template_filter_product_attributes_list( $html, $item, $images ) {

    $post_id    = $item['parent_id'] ? $item['parent_id'] : $item['post_id'];
    $attributes = ProductWrapper::getAttributes( $post_id );

    $attributes_list = '';
    foreach ($attributes as $name => $attr_values) {

        $attributes_list .= '<div>
        <p>' . $name . ': <p>
        <ul class="variation">';

        // Dispaching each attribute values in an array
        $attr_values_arr = explode( '|', $attr_values );

        // The second foreach loop
        foreach ($attr_values_arr as $attr_value){
            $attributes_list .= '<li>' . $attr_value . '</li>';
        }

        $attributes_list .= '</ul>
        </div>';
    }

    $html = str_replace( '[[product_attributes_list]]', $attributes_list, $html );

    return $html;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

I hope that is going to work.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfect! I'm afraid i am asking to much, but do you know how it could manage to just get the attributes i want with 1 Shortcode like: [product_attributes:sizes|color|print] ? Happy to donate if you have a paypal account :)